# kth smallest element in a 2-d matrix (each row is sorted and each column is sorted but not the whole 2-d array is sorted)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, priority-queue, std-pair

A 2d matrix(m*n) is given in which each row as well as column is sorted but the whole 2-d array is not sorted and we have to find kth smallest element of the whole 2-d matrix. I have written a solution using min heap.I have used the following algorithm:

1. Build a min heap of elements from first row.
2. Do following k times.
   …a) Get minimum element (or root) from min heap.
   …b) Replace root with the next element from same column and min-heapify the root.
3. Return the last extracted root.

I have written two Solutions. Both the solutions are working correctly. In the first solution, I have made a heap which store val as well as x and y index. I directly compare the val in my custom compare function i.e. mycompare. In the second Solution, I have made a heap which store only x and y index and send matrix as an argument to mycompare so it compares by referencing to that address. I run both the codes on a very large input and note down the run time. The first Solution takes about 23msec and the 2nd solution takes about 10 sec. Both the solutions are same then why is there so much time gap between the two solutions?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
private:
    struct mycompare{
        bool operator()(pair<int,pair<int,int>> a,pair<int,pair<int,int>> b){
            return a.first>b.first;
        }
    };
public:
    int kthSmallest(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int k) {
        priority_queue<pair<int,pair<int,int>>, vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>>, mycompare> pq;
        for(int i=0;i<matrix[0].size();i++){
            pq.push(make_pair(matrix[i][0],make_pair(i,0)));
        }
        int val;
        pair<int,int> top;
        while(k--){
            val=pq.top().first;
            top=pq.top().second;
            pq.pop();
            if(top.second+1!=matrix.size()){
                pq.push(make_pair(matrix[top.first][top.second+1],make_pair(top.first,top.second+1)));
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
};
class Solution {
private:
    struct mycompare{
        vector<vector<int>> mat;
        mycompare(vector<vector<int>> &matrix){
            this->mat=matrix;
        }
        bool operator()(pair<int,int> a,pair<int,int> b){
            return mat[a.first][a.second]>mat[b.first][b.second];
        }
    };
public:
    int kthSmallest(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int k) {
        priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, mycompare> pq((mycompare(matrix)));
        for(int i=0;i<matrix[0].size();i++){
            pq.push(make_pair(i,0));
        }
        pair<int,int> top;
        while(k--){
            top=pq.top();
            pq.pop();
            if(top.second+1!=matrix.size()){
                pq.push(make_pair(top.first,top.second+1));
            }
        }
        return matrix[top.first][top.second];
    }
};
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > v;
    struct timeval t1,t2;
    double elapsedTime;
    gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);
    cout<<Solution().kthSmallest(v,8357)<<endl;
    gettimeofday(&t2,NULL);
    elapsedTime=(t2.tv_sec-t1.tv_sec)*1000;
    elapsedTime+=(t2.tv_usec-t1.tv_usec)/1000;
    cout<<elapsedTime<<"msec"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Questions about your C++ code are off-topic here on CS.SE, as we don't do coding/implementation questions, but they can often be asked on Stack Overflow.  If you have a question about the algorithm, then you can ask that here if you replace the C++ code with pseudocode, but in this case I suspect your question really fundamentally is about the implementation rather than the algorithm, so it's more suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but check out introselect and related selection algorithms (quickselect, Floyd-Rivest, median of medians), all of which are O(n) time complexity, while your algorithm is O((n + k)log(n)). They can also be run in-place without creating additional data structures (although a heap-based algorithm can do that too, if implemented properly).

Comment: your second comparator makes a *copy* of the matrix, but I doubt this would account fully for the nearly 10 second time loss (unless maybe the matrix is *really* big, i dunno)

Comment: I am not copying the matrix, I am passing it by reference..@vu1p3n0x

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think quickSelect will take O(n*k) because I have to search in whole 2d matrix to find kth smallest ( like it was an unsorted array of n*k elements).. I searched and couldn't find of a better algorithm than O(nlogn).. It would be helpful if you can give some insight into the O(n) algorithm or provide some link..Thank you

Comment: @ShiwangGupta. Search for introselect on Wikipedia. It's O(n) for the same reason that quicksort is O(nlog(n)), except that it only has to look at one of the two subarrays at each level of recursion, effectively removing the factor of log(n).

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, using quickselect kth smallest can be find in O(n) but here total number of elements are n*k.. That's why it will be O(n*k).

Comment: @ShiwangGupta. In that case, you may want to clarify the question a bit. For example, what does "each row as well as column is sorted" mean? Are you trying to find the kth smallest in the whole matrix or in each row or column?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Your matrix is effectively a heap already.

Comment: Also, if you are running the tests subsequent to one another, don't overlook the impact caching will have on the second (presuming there is still some warm data around that can be used in lieu of a full reload for the second run. You can use `clock_gettime` as a much higher resolution timer as well.

Comment: No, I am the running the one taking longer time (10 sec) afterwards..and I have tried running them separately also..Still, its taking much longer time..@DavidC.Rankin